# Visual Studio Search and Replace Line Endings

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 I want to add text to the end of every line of a selected block of text.  The regex approach I'm using is almost working, but not quite.

Here is sample code I want to modify:

```
public string nameOfGeometry
public string color
public string density
```

All three of the above lines need to end either with a semicolon, or perhaps auto-implemented properties.  Here is what I tried:

1. Select all the text I want changed, and press ctrl-h.
2. Toggle "on" regular exressions
3. Enter `$` as my regular expression
4. Enter `{get; set;}` as my replacement text

This does exactly what I want, except that it insert a carriage-return (CRLF) between the `$` and the replacement text.  In other words, my example shown above transforms into this:

```
public string nameOfGeometry
{get; set;}
public string color
{get; set;}
public string density
{get; set;}
```

How do I accomplish this, without the CRLF being added?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I did this and it works

Find: `([^\r\n]+)`
Replace: `$1 {get;set;}`

**Also**
Find: `\r\n`
Replace: `{get;set;}\r\n`

But still I have no idea why it has to be this hard. Still looking for someone come up with simpler solution.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't come up with some thing more easier than this

Find this .. `\r\n`  and replace it with `{get;set;}\r\n`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the wildcard option in the normal search and replace box

- Highlight text
- Goto Search and Replace
- Add `public string ****` in the find box
- Add `public string ***** {get ; set;}` in the replace
  box

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It says "no match found", and there is no option to activate wild-cards.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply left click at the point you want to start adding something ,
Than press alt and while pressing , drag your mouse to the last line you want. 
Then you can just let go the mouse and the alt button and write whatever you want.

Comment: The technique you are describing only works if the added text all starts in the same column.  In my case the column is different on every single line.

Answer (score 2):

Two other answers use `\r\n` as a find clause. I must be doing something different, because I couldn't get that to work; however, with a slight tweak (adding a `?`), it works for me:

find: `\r?\n`

replace: `{get; set;}\r\n`

[Source for the "find" regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.netregularexpressionhelp)&rd=true)